# What does $\tau$ = $\Delta E_{c}$ mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

What does $\tau$ = $\Delta E_c$  mean?

Can anyone help? I'm finding it difficult to find on the internet.

Comment: There is no way we can answer this question without more information

Answer (score 1):

You said that it's from a Brazilian formula sheet. I'm not sure if it's the correct translation, but Google calls work "trabalho" and kinetic energy "energia cinética". So it could be that $\tau$ refers to "trabalho"—work— and $E_c$ "energia cinética"—kinetic energy.

So $\tau = \Delta E_c$ would be the work-kinetic energy theorem (work is the change in kinetic energy).

Comment: That'll be it. Thanks Lobato. And sorry that I forgot to translate "c" to "k".

Answer (score 0):

It could mean almost anything. But I'll guess that $\tau$ is stress and $\delta$ is strain, related linearly by Young's modulus of elasticity, E. The idealized formula for stress and strain in solid materials.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I'm preparing for an exam in Brazil and, looking at the formula sheet for the physics part, I noticed a few I didn't recognise.

I've updated the formula to:  $\tau$ = $\Delta E_{c}$ if that makes it clearer.

Comment: @Ian $\tau$ could be almost anything, but more often used as torque, stress, or in dynamics as 'time constant'. $\Delta$ typically means 'change in" but could also stand for a varioable.  As said you need more info.